# More than 1024 clients using fd_set?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm using `select()` to measure for how long the server doesn't receive any new messages. The code is quite simple and looks like that:

```
int res = -1;
do {
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
    res = select(maxfd+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);
    gettimeofday(&current, NULL);
    if (get_time_diff(current, last) >= diff) {
        // do something
    }
} while (res <= 0);
```

Of course, that doesn't work with more than 1024 connections, since `fd_set` has only 1024 bits. Fortunately, I don't need to store all the FDs, I just need to know when a new connection occurs. So I replaced `maxfd+1` with the next number after the server's FD (which is always the same and in my case equals 18).

Everything seems to be perfectly fine now, and all the clients get correct messages from the server. However, I'm not sure whether it's a valid solution, and it's certainly not a very clean one. Can that cause any problems I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are you suggesting that activity on accepted sockets will wake a `select` call which is sensitive only to the listening socket?  That definitely doesn't seem like a safe assumption.  `select()` has pretty much fallen out of favor, better alternatives are `poll` (portable) and `epoll` (Linux) or completion ports (Windows).

Comment: @BenVoigt Not any activity, of course, but I think it should work in case the connection is new. In my application each clients connects and sends one message only once (always), so I think I can make this assumption. It seems to be sensitive to the listening socket plus one new socket.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, although in TCP usually the data is separate from the datagrams used for the three-way handshake ... and then if you're only `select()`-ing on the listening socket, you could end up stuck in a synchronous `recv()` on your new connection and unable to process other connection attempts in the meantime.  There is an accept queue, so you won't lose clients, but it could mess up timing.  (And a malicious client that connects and then sends zero messages....)

Comment: Are you sure the question should be tagged `c++`? looks like `c` to me...

Comment: @Myst: It is fine C++ code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yap, `select` is limited by design and it's unsafe to use with `fd` values over `1023`.

Honestly, you probably won't find heavy-load production servers using `select` (if you do, than you probably shouldn't use them).

> So I replaced maxfd+1 with the next number after the server's FD (which is always the same and in my case equals 18).

I'm assuming your example is a minimal example and that you aren't just looking into a single listening `fd` (otherwise, you would probably just block on `accept`, which makes more sense).

This will alert you that another file descriptor opened*... However, I feel this isn't the best approach since:

- It will do so only for the first file descriptor...

  New clients will behave according to the state of the first client, their own state will be ignored because their `fd`'s state is never tested.
- It makes your code both fragile and rigid.
- Other file descriptors (non-sockets) could be occupying the specific file descriptor, making the implementation quite broken.
- If you add file descriptors to the set, you still need to test their value.

Better solutions might include:

- Testing for the client's `fd` value and forcing a limit (`if (fd >= 1024) close(fd)`).
- Using `poll` (honestly, that's why it's there - it was introduced to solve the limitations imposed by `select`).
- Using the OS specific API (`epoll` for Linux, `kqueue` for BSD/macOS, etc').
- Using a library that abstracts away the OS specific API (for example, `libev`).

Good Luck!

---

* Unix style systems guarantee that any new file descriptor will be assigned the lowest `fd` value available.

This means that your first client will always receive the server + 1 (assuming you didn't open or close any other file descriptor).

But newer file descriptors will be assigned higher values (unless a lower file descriptor becomes available). So, while you're testing for the first client's state, the other clients are never polled.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the function of the first parameter to `select()`.  Passing `maxfd+1` does not make `select()` sensitive to events on file descriptor `maxfd+1`, even if that is the next descriptor selected.  The `select()` call in the question wakes when the listening socket is ready to have `accept()` called -- that, and not the numeric value of the new fd (which doesn't even exist until *after* `accept()` anyway), is the mechanism that detects new connections.

Comment: @BenVoigt, I'm aware of that, but it does limit the FD_SET, so it ignores all the file descriptors that are higher than `maxfd + 1`. It's unable to tell when clients have pending data or are available for writing.

Comment: That `select()` call is unable to tell when clients have pending data because `FD_ZERO` excludes them from the sensitivity set.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I think the example code is just a short example. If OP wanted just to test the listening socket, than (I'm assuming), OP would just block on `accept` instead of wait for `select`. This assumption is the reason why my answer has these extra details. It's obvious that only a single `sockfd` was added to the set in the example, but I was assuming that the actual code adds more. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: I'm not using blocking `accept()` exactly because it just waits for new connections, and I can't do anything if the waiting time exceeds the limit. Actually, non-blocking `accept()` seems to be working. I just didn't think of it. Thanks!

Comment: @vgeclair - Sidenote: you can always exit a blocking `accept` using a signal.